# Why does browserify need sudo permission for local installs?

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

When installing [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) locally, why does it require administrator privileges?

With `broswerify` listed as a dependency in my local `package.json`, a simple `npm install` *sometimes* yields an EACCESS error:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/user/.npm/browserify/8.1.3'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/user/.npm/browserify/8.1.3']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/user/.npm/browserify/8.1.3',
npm ERR!   parent: 'my-app' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Obviously I can use `sudo` to circumvent the issue, but why should I have to?

Comment: Does any of '/Users/user/.npm/' exist and what are the permissions on it?

Comment: @DanD. Why would it need to install anything in `/Users/user/.npm/`? I am installing locally, not globally. `/Users/user/.npm/` is for global installs.

Comment: `~/.npm` is the location of the npm package cache.

Comment: @DanD. So by that rationale, all `npm install`s should prefix `sudo`? Not sure I agree.

Comment: Then again, `~/.npm` is your home and you shouldn't need `sudo` to touch it. I'm not familiar with distros that use `npm` but I wonder if `~/.npm/browserify/8.1.3` is really the folder it is trying to create (which should be perfetly legal) or if its the name of the script that is throwing the error.

Comment: Maybe your `~/.npm` folder was created by `root` and have messed up permissions.

Comment: @Havenard my `~/.npm` is owned by my user: `drwxr-xr-x  513 user  staff  17442 26 Mar 00:21 .npm`. Doesn't explain why other packages can be installed just fine without permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some most likely at some point along the way you installed something with `sudo npm`. You **never** have to do that. However, once you've done it, you may have to use `sudo npm cache clean` or `sudo rm -rf /Users/user/.npm` to get back to the normal state, then going forward no more sudos ever. This is entirely about filesystem permissions and has zero to do directly with npm or browserify.

Based on the details in your comments specifically run `ls -ld /Users/user/.npm/browserify` because the problem is when npm tries to `mkdir` within that, meaning that directory is probably not writeable for `user`.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this. The `browserify` folder was indeed owned by `root`. A clean of the cache and we're back to normal. Thanks.